# Discord.JS - Bot toggling commands

Tags: javascript, bots, discord.js

I am currently at a road block on developing my bot. Does anyone know how to create toggle commands for Discord.JS? I am trying to allow users to toggle specific commands on & off.

Comment: Cool idea. The way you implement this depends on the way you've implemented your commands. If you've attempted anything, please share it with us so we can help. If you haven't attempted anything, please start somewhere :)

Comment: An example on how it can be done can be found at https://github.com/discordjs/Commando

Answer (score 0):

If you want it switch "on live" you need database for that.

you command execute code must be like:

```
if(!message.member.hasPermission("ADMINISTRATOR") ) {
  //SELECT SOMETHINK FROM DATA BASE, IF NO RESULT, THEN RETURN
}
```

If not on live you can add verification by role or permissions or id

```
if(!member.roles.some(r=>["666026501472518167", "ROLEID"].includes(r.id))) return
if(!message.member.hasPermission("ADMINISTRATOR") return
if(!member.user.id.some(u=>["666026501472518167", "USERID"].includes(u.id))) return
```

Comment: I think you misunderstood, the author wants users to be able to toggle commands themselves (Example: `!disable command`)

Comment: Hmm, but anyway for right toggle it  need data base or config file for commands.The question has many different solutions.

Comment: Agreed, you'll definitely need some form of persistence.